# Django admin for User's objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-views

I would like to allow a User to have an admin interface to their own Video objects. I was planning on writing some views that allowed things like setting attributes like "published" or deleting objects.

I've started looking into using django's Admin site - but that seems like it might be overly complicated for what I want (just deleting/ setting the published attribute).

Is one approach better than the other? Writing something from scratch or using the Admin site?

If I were to write something from scratch - what is the correct way to achieve ModelAdmin style actions (ie. delete_selected(queryset, request))

Comment: It would be better if you use the Admin Site and overriding the function and templates that you need to customize. Rest depends upon your requirements at hand in exact.

Comment: What you want to do is extremely tedious and time consuming work, that could be done in a few minutes with the Django-Admin. I would only consider it if I didn't want the users to have access the the admin panel in any way for security reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what the admin should be used for! How could it be too complicated? Even writing a handful of lines of HTML would take longer.

If you built this yourself, no matter how simple, you'll have to define views that list objects, validate input, check permissions, write HTML, implement some kind of multiple action system that maps to python code, ....

Assuming you don't want to do that:

You're going to want to look into making [multiple admin sites](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#multiple-admin-sites-in-the-same-urlconf) and filtering admin results to only those that belong to the user via [overriding the `queryset` method on a `ModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.queryset)

```
# pasted from docs
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(author=request.user)
```

Comment: Is there a way to override the login to the admin that is presented?

Comment: Google is your friend! https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.login_template